# mule rpc versus JQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, mule

Mule provides a Client side [Ajax library](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/AJAX+Transport+Reference), I am specifically puzzled about the rpc method it exposes. When would one use this over a regular [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call.

And what do they mean by the below sentence in their documentation

> Mule provides a powerful JavaScript client with full Ajax support that
>   can be used to interact with Mule flows directly in the browser.

From what i understand the flow exposes a "HTTP endpoint" which is used by the JS Ajax library, and this endpoint can be invoked using any regular JS library.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario where this provides value would be initiating events from the mule flow.

In their example **Listening to Server Events**

You can have a flow which sends data to the client

**Mule Flow**:

```
<flow name="AjaxBridge">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="football.scores"/>

    <ajax:outbound-endpoint channel="/football/scores"/>
</flow>
```

**Client page**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mule.subscribe("/football/scores", scoresCallback);

    function scoresCallback(message)
    {
        console.debug("data:" + message.data);

        if (!message.data)
        {
            console.debug("bad message format " + message);
            return;
        }

        // logic goes here
        ...
    }
</script>
```

In this scenario an event on the server triggered data to be sent to the client where as the JQuery Ajax library is only about the client making requests to the server.

Comment: I agree with your example, however I was specifically asking about the RPC method